# Firebase limitToLast Query

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, listener

My question maybe a silly one, I´ve read the documentation but haven´t got a solution to my question. When I use limitToLast to get the last 15 messages (lets say from 5-20) and if I delete the 20th message, the childListener returns me messages like this (5-6-7-8-9-10-11-12-13-14-15-16-17-18-19-4)... As you can see the last item is number 4.
The code is like so:
`messagesListener = FBMessagesRef.limitToLast(15).addChildEventListener(new ChildEventListener()`, how can I fix it and dont get the 4th item

Comment: If the current answers don't help you, edit your question to include the [minimal code that reproduces the problem](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). Right now we have no way to know how your `ChildEventListener` is implemented, which is likely part of the problem.

Comment: I am having the same problem. Is there any solution.?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you're getting the last 15 digits when you set the value to 15, change the `limitToLast` value to `-1` to get the last Firebase value.
Change your code to below snippet.

```
messagesListener = FBMessagesRef.limitToLast(-1).addChildEventListener(new ChildEventListener(),
```

Answer (score 0):

Firebase official documentation says that if the limit value is less than the item count in the database, then it will read all the items in the database. It is clear i guess.

> **limitToLast(limit) returns firebase.database.Query**
>
> Generates a new Query object limited to the last specific number of
>   children.
>
> The limitToLast() method is used to set a maximum number of children
>   to be synced for a given callback. If we set a limit of 100, we will
>   initially only receive up to 100 child_added events. **If we have less**
>   **than 100 messages stored in our database, a child_added event will**
>   **fire for each message.** However, if we have over 100 messages, we will
>   only receive a child_added event for the last 100 ordered messages. As
>   items change, we will receive child_removed events for each item that
>   drops out of the active list, so that the total number stays at 100.

Comment: so how can I avoid  this behaviour, so it don´t mess with the order of the messages?

Comment: You can create an arraylist of the whole items and make the opreations over the array. See https://github.com/firebase/FirebaseUI-Android/blob/master/database/src/main/java/com/firebase/ui/database/FirebaseArray.java as an official firebase array example with childeventlistener.