# Android Firebase OrderByChild limitToLast is not working

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I am trying to search the 10 data using OrderByChild.limitToLast(10) in Firebase Database.
But it is not returning the 10 last items.
So I didn't set the count in query and got the all items.
In iOS Firebase, sort query is working well but in android, it has issue.

How can I get the latest items using limitToLast() method?

```
Query firstPageQuery = ref.child("survey-aeroplate-global").orderByChild("renderUploaded").limitToLast(10);
    firstPageQuery.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot surveysSnapshot) {}
```

[image]

Comment: Maybe you would like to share some code and your database structure so everyone can see what's going on?

Comment: I have updated my question with code snippet and screenshots.

Comment: But it is not returning the 10 last items - Tell us how/in what order you are getting elements? Is it something like this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39796451/firebase-limittolast-query?utm_medium=organic&utm_source=google_rich_qa&utm_campaign=google_rich_qa

Comment: I am getting 10 items by ascending but not getting last 10 items in total items in Firebase database.

Comment: Those 10 items that you are getting, are you sure are not the last added? Please responde with @AlexMamo

Comment: yes, I am sure, I am going to get 10 latest items sorted by "renderUploaded" key.

Comment: @AlexMamo, do you have any good idea? It is working well in iOS

Comment: What is the order of those 10 items now?

Comment: by ascending. but not latest.If I get all items, I can see the latest items but I can't see those in result by using query.

Answer (score 1):

You should add indexOn to firebase rules.

```
{
  "rules": {
    "survey-aeroplate-global":{
      ".indexOn":["renderUploaded"],
      ".write":"auth!=null",
      ".read": "auth!=null"
    }  
  }
}
```

Comment: What else you want me to write? It is just firebase database rules,add this code to rules then you can use `orderByChild("renderUploaded")`